# Wrap Header Text in Datatable:

Tags: css, datatables

I am using `Datatable` to show user details on the jsp page:
In my table I have so many column because of that header text are coming in multiple line please find the Image below:

[image]

I would like to show header text in single line:
Required Header Text:

[image]

Is there any way so that I can forcefully set the text of header?

Comment: Can you post the code please

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just set the `white-space` property :

```css
table thead th {
  white-space: nowrap
}
```

If you want to target dataTables tables only

```css
table.dataTable thead th {
  white-space: nowrap
}
```